# Webpage not loading while scrapping in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I have a dataset which contains URL of Just Dial website for which I am trying to extract few information like seller name. Below I have attached a sample data

```
dict_test  = {"Id" : [1000, 1001, 1002],
             "Online_url" : ['https://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/Sunrise-Info-Solutions-Pvt-Ltd-Near-Airtel-Gallery/022PXX22-XX22-220719102528-J5Q2_BZDET?xid=TXVtYmFpIE1vYmlsZSBEZWFsZXJz',
                            'https://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/Riddhi-Siddhi-Mobile-Gallery-Electronic-Opposite-Jain-Plaza-Ambernath/022PXX22-XX22-210519191020-K2U6_BZDET?xid=TXVtYmFpIE1vYmlsZSBEZWFsZXJz',
                            'https://www.justdial.com/Mumbai/Bharat-Communication-Opposite-Vibgyor-School-Goregaon-West/022PXX22-XX22-130103150323-S4V9_BZDET?xid=TXVtYmFpIE1vYmlsZSBEZWFsZXJz']}
df_test = pd.DataFrame(dict_test)
```

And below script is what I have used to extract Seller information

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument( "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\admin\Downloads\chromedriver_lates\chromedriver.exe', options = options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://www.justdial.com/')
time.sleep(2)

def webpage_extract(min_count, max_count, df_test, folder, file_name):
    for i in range(min_count,max_count):
        try:
            driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
            driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
            # Switch to the new window and open new URL
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
            driver.get(df_test['Online_url'].iloc[i])
            time.sleep(5)
        except TimeoutException as ex:
            isrunning = 0
            print("Exception has been thrown.")

        try:
            myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'fn')))
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Loading took too much time!")
        
### Below command is used to close the Pop-up
        try:
            driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="best_deal_detail_div"]/section/span').click()
            driver.find_element("xpath", '//*[@id="best_deal_detail_div"]/section/span').click()
        except:
            "Pop_Up"
            
        try:
            seller_info=driver.find_element("xpath", "/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/h1/span/span").text
            print("Seller_Name: ", seller_info)
        except:
            seller_info="Extraction_Error"
            
        print("Iteration {} : Information Extracted for Seller {}".format(i, seller_info))
        driver.delete_all_cookies()
        # Closing the tab
        driver.close()
        time.sleep(2)
    return None


%time webpage_extract(0, len(df_test), df_test, folder, file_name)
```

The issue with above code is that for 1st URL data is extracting correct information however for 2nd URL the web-page is not loading and is showing about:blank URL. Is there any way to resolve this or to skip this URL and move on to next URL?

Comment: After driver.get() just check if driver.current_url ==df_test['Online_url'].iloc[i] and proceed to do your code.

Answer (score 0):

you should not close the driver at the end of webpage_extract.